Enumitem wide lists
Shamefully, the enumitem settings still confuse me. I want to set up a wide list, but level-two settings, I could not do. How can I make the sub-item as in the following figure? I do not want to open up the same topic again and again, so I would be obliged if you could include the possible three options for level-two, and an additional option for level-one.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    label=(\alph*),
    wide,
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=(\roman*),
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item this an item
    \item this an item
    \item \begin{enumerate}
        \item this is a sub-item
        \item this is a sub-item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


Here's how I'd go about it. There are many ways to achieve the same output since several of the parameters depend on others.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{
    label=(\alph*),
    wide=0pt,
}

\begin{document}

\section{Type 1}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=(\roman*),
    wide % equivalent to wide=\parindent
}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1][1]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \kant[2][1]
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \kant[3][1]
\end{enumerate}

\section{Type 2}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=(\roman*),
    wide,
    leftmargin=\parindent
}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1][1]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \kant[2][1]
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \kant[3][1]
\end{enumerate}

\section{Type 3}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=(\roman*),
    align=left,
    left=\parindent..2\parindent,
}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1][1]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \kant[2][1]
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \kant[3][1]
\end{enumerate}

\section{Now change top level too}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{
    label=(\alph*),
    align=left,
    left=0pt..1.3\parindent,
}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1][1]
    \item \kant[2][1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


P.S. The enumitem settings often confuse me too :)

In some of my projects I have the \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} setting. How can I adjust your solution to that setting also?

@blackened Use a fixed width in that case. In the article class, for example, parindent is 15pt

Re “The enumitem settings often confuse me too”. You are not alone. I decided to keep the LaTeX list parameters, but now I think I had to replace them with more intuitive ones (much like left). (Note: I’m the author.)
